How to compare real-time physiological data between pre-defined time blocks
I have a set of physiological data for approx. 20 patients measured per second over approximately 8 to 10 minutes. The data is grouped into the following blocks of time: calibration, test, first intervention, second intervention.
I want to test for significant changes between the blocks.

Is it better to compare the blocks of data by using means or percentage increase/decrease?
Is it better to calculate percentage increase/decrease based on baseline or previous block data?
Is a paired t-test appropriate or are other tests better?

Thanks!

You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one post.

I think it might be better if you stated the exact unit value for each time block instead of using percentages, just to ensure the reader understands the data properly. After that, you could include a graph displaying each block’s percent change from the baseline, which can help the reader visualize the data and how quickly or slowly it changes over time (using the graph’s slope at the transitions between each time block). Unfortunately, I don’t know much about t-tests to advise you on that.
